# Will QDomElement be invalid out of the function which creates it?

Tags: c++, qt, variables, dom

I want to create `QDomElement` like this:

```
class DomParser : public QObject
{
public:
    DomParser();
QDomDocument doc;
QDomElement* root;
}

QDomElement* DomParser::domParameterStatus(UniversalMessage* parameterStatus)
{

    root = &(doc.createElement("doc"));
    QDomText latin = doc.createTextNode("Ars longa vita brevis");
    QDomText english = doc.createTextNode("Art is long, life is short");
    doc.appendChild(root);
    root.appendChild(quote);
    root.appendChild(translation);
    ...
    return root;
}
```

I make root as a member in class DomParser only to save the dom tree struct, **but will root's children be valid out of the function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so long as doc is not destroyed.  From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html):

> Since elements, text nodes, comments, processing instructions, etc., cannot exist outside the context of a document, the document class also contains the factory functions needed to create these objects. The node objects created have an ownerDocument() function which associates them with the document within whose context they were created. The DOM classes that will be used most often are QDomNode, QDomDocument, QDomElement and QDomText.
>
> The parsed XML is represented internally by a tree of objects that can be accessed using the various QDom classes. All QDom classes only reference objects in the internal tree. The internal objects in the DOM tree will get deleted once the last QDom object referencing them and the QDomDocument itself are deleted.

Also, appendChild reparents the child node, so as long as root is their parent and exists, they're not going anywhere.

Comment: Qt5 says "the DOM tree will get deleted once the last QDom object referencing them **OR** the QDomDocument itself are deleted".

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: yes, all elements, once added to a parent node, will continue to be valid for as long as their parent exists.

Your code here is incorrect, and will not compile.  This line: `root = &(doc.createElement("doc"));` is trying to create a pointer to a temporary variable.  Not only is this a very bad idea, leading to an almost certain crash, it's not at all necessary.  QDom is designed to be entirely value based, you do not need to use pointers at all.  Here's the fixed version of your method:

```
QDomElement DomParser::domParameterStatus(UniversalMessage* parameterStatus)
{
    root = doc.createElement("doc");
    QDomText latin = doc.createTextNode("Ars longa vita brevis");
    QDomText english = doc.createTextNode("Art is long, life is short");
    doc.appendChild(root);
    root.appendChild(quote);
    root.appendChild(translation);
    ...
    return root;
}
```